Problem with firebase notification redirecting to activity
I use firebase for notification handling, and I want notifications with TEST_ACTION which is my clickable action in payload to send me to my RecognizeUserActivity, everything works okay except one problem, when I put app in background and in a meanwhile notification with TEST_ACTION is recieved when I resume app it send me to my RecognizeUserActivity, but what I want is to send me only on notification click in drop-down menu.
This is my firebaseMessage class
private fun sendNotification(message: RemoteMessage) {
    val title = message.notification?.title.toString()
    val body = message.notification?.body.toString()

    val notificationIntent: Intent = if (message.notification?.clickAction.toString() == "TEST_ACTION") {
        Intent(this, RecognizeUserActivity::class.java).apply {
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
            putExtra("message", body)
        }
    } else {
        Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
            putExtra("message", body)
        }
    }
    val requestCode = System.currentTimeMillis().toInt()
    val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

    val channelId = "APP"
    val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    val notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder =
        NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())

    val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            channelId,
            "AUTHORIZATION NOTIFICATIONS",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    val notificationId = System.currentTimeMillis().toInt()
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build())
}

override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(message)
    sendNotification(message)
}

override fun handleIntent(intent: Intent) {
    try {
        if (intent.extras != null) {
            val builder = RemoteMessage.Builder("FirebaseMessagingService")
            for (key in intent.extras!!.keySet()) {
                builder.addData(key!!, intent.extras?.getString(key))
            }
            onMessageReceived(builder.build())

        } else {
            super.handleIntent(intent)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        super.handleIntent(intent)
    }
}


Please also add the intent-filter(s) from the AndroidManifest.xml, which is the receiving side.

Check your AndroidManifest.xml, i try this (check your intents filter in your activitys):
<activity
        android:name=".mainModule.view.TestActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FireLinkPeru.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.neutechperu.TEST_ACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".loginModule.view.LoginActivity"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".mainModule.view.MainActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FireLinkPeru.NoActionBar" />

